# Can't add System.Drawing namespace in C# console application

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, system.drawing

I'm trying to add the System.Drawing namespace in my C# console application but when I go to use it's 'Image' type, I get the error:

"The type name 'Image' could not be found it the namespace 'System.Drawing'. This type has been forwarded to assembly System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.20, Culture=neutral, Consider adding reference to that assembly".

I have already went to Project>Add Reference>COM>System.Drawing.dll>Select>OK to add it but the error is still there.

[image: Add references window]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use the "COM" section in that dialog. Use "Assemblies" instead:

[image: Assemblies]

Note how this gives newer versions (4.0) instead of old versions (2.0 / 2.4).

If there is no "Assemblies" section, check that you really created a C# .NET Framework project. Likely you chose C# .NET Core.

If you want to stick with .NET Core, use the Nuget package [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common)